# Can't get social media buttons/div to right align

Tags: css, alignment

I can't seem to get these social buttons to fully right align. I've set the margins of the page to "0" and have set the alignment to right="0" - any ideas what else to do?

The url is: http://www.radiobootcamp.org/TEST.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
 style="text-align:right"
```

to that twitter div

Answer (score 0):

This will allow to align the social media buttons to the right.
The initial width of a block level element like div or p is **auto**. This makes it expand to occupy all available horizontal space within its containing block.

```
.twitter {
    border: 0 none;
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 5px;
    top: 400px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that they have float defined as left. I would suggest to add `float:right !important;` and if not working put each button in a different `div` with `height:auto` and `width:auto` and put `float:right` on that `div` container.